# Force whitespace to appear between fixed-width div and the right side of page

Tags: html, css

I have a question for the front-end web development experts out there which is stumping me.

On my page, I have a sidebar which is fixed on the right side of the page, and then a large block of content (fixed-width) that takes up more than the width of the browser window. The problem is, the content on the far right side of the div can't be seen because it's behind the fixed sidebar.

[Here is a super stripped down example of my issue in jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/94/)

**EDIT:** [Here is a more complete example of my issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/92/)

I thought that simply applying padding-right: "width of sidebar"px to either the body or to a wrapper div, or applying margin-right: "width of sidebar"px to the content div should fix the issue, but neither works. I don't want to resort to putting in a filler div unless there is no way to accomplish this effect with CSS.

I did a search for the issue on google and so, but all I found were questions about how to *remove* whitespace from the right side, which is the opposite of what I want to do.

Thanks to anyone who can solve this stumper!

**EDIT:** After seeing a multiple questions about why I can't simply set things up differently, I thought I'd clarify by showing a more in-depth example of what I'm trying to accomplish. You can see that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/92/). The columns in the table must be fixed-width, and I want to be able to see the full contents of the last column. Hope that helps clarify things!

Comment: Is using fixed your best option here?  Why not try using float left and right?  Why do you need to make that right col fixed?

Comment: Be careful with floats! It can be done, but in my experience you can better use position absolute for these kind of things together with percentages or pixels.

Comment: Instead of having a pixel width on your two columns, could you use 10% width on the sidebar and 90% width on the main content? Also, like Lokase, I get the feeling there might be a better implementation for your particular design. Could you post a screenshot of the mockup?

Comment: @Chris here's what I'm actually trying to implement: http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/92/

The columns must be fixed-width and I want to be able to see the full contents of last column.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the screen is smaller than the width of the table + the sidebar? Now the content disappears behind the sidebar, but do you want to happen?

Comment: @Bart, when the screen is smaller than the width of the table and sidebar, I want the user to be able to scroll to the left and right using the browser's horizontal scroll-bar, and when they scroll all the way to the right, I want them to be able to see the entire last column. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Right now the table does exactly what I want it to do, except that I can't see the entire last column because it's hidden under the sidebar. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the wrapper position absolute with a left 0 and right of 110px, which you also can put on the content div instead of the wrapper. Just to give you a hint... See http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/98/

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px; right:110px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Edit**
I also create a version with a max-width that makes sure the content will never exceed 900px, but if there is less room it will respect the sidebar as well... http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/102/

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-right: 110px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the content div *must* be fixed-width.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the screen is smaller than the width of the div + the sidebar?

Comment: The wrapper has a *fixed* width and the sidebar has a *fixed* width. How much degree of freedom is there left for the content to be of a none fixed width?

Comment: See my other solution with a max width. The content will never be bigger than the 'fixed width', but can be smaller if the window is smaller.

Comment: @Bart, thanks for your suggestion. That would work if I didn't *have* to have a fixed width div. In my actual implementation the "content" div is a table with fixed-width columns, so I can't use max-width.

Comment: I'm choosing your answer even though my own is what worked for me. This will certainly work in many cases. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already came up with a jquery solution, but I think you could get by with a simple css rule:

```
tr td:last-child { padding-right: 100px; }
```

It just sets padding on the last `td` in each `tr`, equal to the fixed right sidebar width.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. +1 for a great suggestion. Unfortunately it wouldn't work in my particular case because all the columns have to be the same width because of the kinds of content I'm putting in them. For others, that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted fixed width, but this works how you want I believe without worrying about user screen resolution. I just added float:right and width:100%; to the content div and it looks good to me. Try this code:

```
#content {
border: 1px solid #444;
background: #aaa;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the input! Unfortunately, I have to set my width in pixels. Take a look at my more fleshed-out example here to see what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/92/ . The columns in that table must be fixed-width for what I'm doing with them.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution to my issue. I simply used jQuery to set the width of the body to the width of the table *plus* the width of the right sidebar. Worked like a charm.

Here's the code I used if future developers stumble upon this page with the same question:

$('body').css('width', $('table').width() + 150 + 'px');

Where 150 is the width of the sidebar.